# Get text to String from website with a delay in Java

Tags: java, html, http, htmlunit

Java noob here.

I am trying to get the text from "https://hektor.webuntis.com/WebUntis/monitor?school=Domgymnasium%20Verden&monitorType=subst&format=Schueler" to a String (or whatever).

However, when using HtmlUnit or jsoup I run into a problem.
Upon loading the page, it doesn't instantly show the content I need.
It displays "loading webuntis..." for a few frames (depending on the connection speed I guess)
and proceeds to show the content afterwards.

Using HtmlUnit or jsoup, I just get "loading webuntis..." to a String.
How can I skip this loading sequence and get the content I need?

Comment: It might help to add a sample code to let otheres reproducing your problem and mabe help you with a solution.